# hadoop -appendToFile on Google Compute Engine cluster

Tags: hadoop, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am having trouble performing the hadoop fs shell command, -appendToFile, on a GCE hadoop cluster.  I have had success with other hadoop shell commands (*e.g.,* -cat, -put, -mv) on the GCE cluster.  In addition, I am able to use -appendToFile on a different hadoop cluster.  However, I am unable to use -appendToFile on the GCE hadoop cluster. Syntax I have tried:

```
hdfs dfs -appendToFile two.log /tmp/test/one.log
```

yields:

"appendToFile: Failed to close file /tmp/test/one.log. Lease recovery is in progress. Try again later." Where one.log is an existing file on the hdfs, and two.log is an existing file on the local file system.

In addition:

```
hadoop fs -appendToFile two.log /tmp/test/one.log
```

yields many errors beginning with:

java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try.

I am not familiar with these errors, and I believe my syntax use is correct.  I have confirmed other hadoop commands are working with similar syntax.  And the same commands work on other clusters.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the value of DEFAULT_FS if you used bdutil, or what's the value of fs.default.name in your /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf/core-site.xml? (Or other ${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/core-site.xml if you didn't use bdutil or Click-to-Deploy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you may be running into a known issue that apparently impacts the `append` command most prominently, if you happen to be running a default bdutil or Click-to-Deploy created Hadoop cluster with 2 datanodes, and if `dfs.replication` is still at its default value of `3`: [HDFS-4600
HDFS file append failing in multinode cluster](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-4600)

In a recent `bdutil` [release 1.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/dLDvzDMdVFw), the default dfs.replication is now `2` since default settings are already on Persistent Disk; the replication of 2 is a tradeoff to allow Hadoop to still have greater availability against single-node failures, while the underlying Persistent Disk provides durability. So, if you pick up the latest changes and/or manually set `dfs.replication` to a lower number, or increase the number of datanodes, append should start working.

Comment: Thanks very much for this very effective answer!  I'll just comment here that I found I needed to change `UPLOAD_FILES+=("libexec/configure_mrv2_mem.py")`  to `UPLOAD_FILES+=(${BDUTIL_DIR}/libexec/configure_mrv2_mem.py)` in `hadoop2_env.sh` for the [1.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/dLDvzDMdVFw) release. Otherwise, it's working great so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the report! Fixed (additionally for querytools and ambari) in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/pull/12 (commit https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/commit/1d3aac816204ffdeebe4beded3aedb7e9dd147fd)